# Speedata and XPath

Tags: xslt-1.0, speedatapublisher

Unfortunately I can't handle the XPath syntax in the Laout.xml of Speedata .
I've been programming XSL for years and maybe I'm a bit preburdened.
The XML I'm trying to evaluate has the following structure:

```
<export>
    <object>
        <fields>
            <field key="demo1:DISPLAY_NAME" lang="de_DE" origin="default" ftype="string">Anwendungsbild</field>
            <field key="demo1:DISPLAY_NAME" lang="en_UK" origin="inherit" ftype="string">application picture</field>
            <field key="demo1:DISPLAY_NAME" lang="es_ES" origin="self" ftype="string">imagen de aplicación</field>
        </fields>
    </object>
</export>
```

The attempt to output the element node with the following XPath fails.

```
export/object/fields/field[@key='demo1:DISPLAY_NAME' and @lang='de_DE' and @origin='default']
```

How do I formulate the query in Speedata Publisher, please?

Thnk you for our Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speedata software only supports a small subset of XPath. You have two options

- preprocess the data with the provided Saxon XSLT processor
- iterate through the data yourself:

```xml
<Layout xmlns="urn:speedata.de:2009/publisher/en"
   xmlns:sd="urn:speedata:2009/publisher/functions/en">

   <Record element="export">
        <ForAll select="object/fields/field">
            <Switch>
                <Case test="@key='demo1:DISPLAY_NAME' and @lang='de_DE' and @origin='default'">
                    <SetVariable variable="whatever" select="."/>
                </Case>
            </Switch>
        </ForAll>
        <Message select="$whatever"></Message>
   </Record>
</Layout>
```

(given your input file as `data.xml`)